# how to auto setup a "AT" schedule job once after reboot

Tags: shell, automation, cron, centos, reboot

when I loging in  centos as root via ssh
i type

```
at  -f /etc/at_stopssh.txt now + 5 minutes
```

and it works, one schedule job has been setup sucessfully

at_stopssh.txt  include a simple command shows below

```
service sshd stop
```

---

then i try to automate it after rebooting by adding it into
rc.local file.  so i add a new line in the rc.local

```
at  -f /etc/at_stopssh.txt now + 5 minutes
```

after reboot .  i checked by atq command, it seems there is no job schedule has been added.

I try it in another way.  i added another newline into rc.local file shows below

```
echo "/sbin/service/service /usr/sbin/sshd/sshd stop"|/usr/bin/at now + 5 minutes
```

and it was non funcational at all again.

for your reference it is my env file content shows below

```
env | sort > /tmp/env.at



_=/bin/env
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
HISTSIZE=1000
HOME=/root
HOSTNAME=377pc.cn
INPUTRC=/etc/inputrc
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LESSOPEN=|/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
LOGNAME=root
LS_COLORS=no=00:fi=00:di=00;34:ln=00;36:pi=40;33:so=00;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=01;05;37;41:mi=01;05;37;41:ex=00;32:*.cmd=00;32:*.exe=00;32:*.com=00;32:*.btm=00;32:*.bat=00;32:*.sh=00;32:*.csh=00;32:*.tar=00;31:*.tgz=00;31:*.arj=00;31:*.taz=00;31:*.lzh=00;31:*.zip=00;31:*.z=00;31:*.Z=00;31:*.gz=00;31:*.bz2=00;31:*.bz=00;31:*.tz=00;31:*.rpm=00;31:*.cpio=00;31:*.jpg=00;35:*.gif=00;35:*.bmp=00;35:*.xbm=00;35:*.xpm=00;35:*.png=00;35:*.tif=00;35:
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
PWD=/root
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
SSH_CLIENT=121.228.206.52 31795 22
SSH_CONNECTION=121.228.206.52 31795 205.185.124.26 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
TERM=xterm
USER=root
```

My question is what is wrong with it? how could i  aotomatically setting up a new  "AT" job and make it functional after a reboot?

Many thanks
Austin

Comment: Is root getting any mail regarding the `at` job or are there any log entries? Try adding `-m` to the `at` command so you get mail regardless of other output.

Answer (score 1):

At-jobs are cleared upon restart; they’re not appropriate for cron jobs that should occur after restart.

Luckily enough, there is a special `@reboot` crontab entry that lets you run a job after reboot. If you need to wait 5 minutes, you can insert an appropriate `sleep`.

However, if what you're really trying to do is prevent the SSH server from being started in the first place, you should `chkconfig` the service off. I'm not 100% sure what the name is on CentOS, but on Ubuntu it would be `chkconfig ssh off`.

Comment: hi Edward Z. Yang Thanks for the reply. chkconfig ssh off will stop ssh service while i try to has ssh be active and auto stop its service after 5 mins . so i could have enough time to decide if i should disable ssh or not .  i just want to leave a backdoor in case i need ssh connection .then i could reboot the server and regain ssh connection.

Comment: You're better off disabling password SSHs, or moving the port to a non-standard location. Not having remote access to a server is a pain.

Comment: Your first sentence is true for queued `at` jobs, but it doesn't apply to queuing `at` jobs immediately after boot that are expected to be run soon thereafter (unless the system is rebooted sooner after having just been booted than the time until the `at` job is scheduled for).

Comment: Yes. But adding manual entries to your rc files is... dubious at best.